# Retrieve options set through a plugin

Tags: plugins, actions

I am creating a simple "global settings" plugin, which simply saves a few text fields. Saving works as intended, and I can retrieve my data in frontend as follows:

```
<?php $options = get_option('wpglobalsettings'); ?>
<?php echo $options['wpglobalsettings_image1']; ?>
```

What I would like though, would be to avoid having to call get_option('wpglobalsettings'); on each page I plan to use my plugin on.

So I was thinking I could add my $options to an action hook. I did the following, but it doesn't work ( I get an empty array.

```
function wp_global_settings_frontend(){
  $options = get_option( 'wpglobalsettings' );
}

add_action('the_content', 'wp_global_settings_frontend');
```

Can You help? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, [the_content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content)
is a filter hook and not action. Secondly, it will only work when post content will be access on your site front end. You can probably make use of [global](http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables) variables instead.

e.g.

```
$options = get_option( 'wpglobalsettings' );
```

and then use wherever you want to access as follows -

```
global $options;
```

Comment: I did it like this and it works

Answer (score 0):

Because your $options variable is limited to just the scope of the wp_global_settings_frontend() function.

What you want to do here is set it as a constant instead of a local variable.

```
function wp_global_settings_frontend(){
  define('OPTIONS', get_option('wpglobalsettings');
}

add_action('the_content', 'wp_global_settings_frontend');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

Just make sure the hook you tie it to fires before you use it.

Also, maybe pick a constant name that will be more unique.

Comment: This looks cool, but when I try it and reload my theme it's blank O__O I'm sure it's me doing something wrong

Comment: Like WisdmLabs said 'the_content' isn't the right hook for this. How were you trying to access your constant after you set it?